# Scala: Why is this Future.traverse slow? The body is not running in parallel

Tags: scala

```
val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis
for {
  data <- Future.traverse(lessons) { lesson =>
    val startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis
    for ( f <- analyticsService.getData(lesson.id) ) yield {
      println(s"Future took ${startTime2 - System.currentTimeMillis}"); f
    }
  }
} yield {
  println(s"end ${startTime - System.currentTimeMillis}")
  data
}
```

The `analyticsService.getData(lesson.id)` seem to run sequentially instead of in parallel. To show this case I replaced `analyticsService.getData(lesson.id)` with `Future { Thread.sleep(1000) }` and the printed results were

```
Future took -1000
Future took -1001
Future took -1000
Future took -1001
Future took -1001
Future took -1001
Future took -1001
Future took -2001
Future took -2001
Future took -2002
Future took -2002
Future took -2001
Future took -3000
Future took -3001
Future took -3002
Future took -3002
Future took -3002
Future took -4000
Future took -4001
Future took -4002
Future took -4002
Future took -4002
Future took -4002
Future took -4002
Future took -5001
Future took -5001
Future took -5002
Future took -5002
Future took -5002
Future took -5004
Future took -5004
....
Future took -62601
Future took -62601
Future took -62601
Future took -62601
Future took -62601
Future took -62601
Future took -62601
Future took -62600
Future took -63597
Future took -63598
Future took -63598
Future took -63599
Future took -63601
Future took -63601
```

From this it looks like batches of Futures are run in parallel but what are some ways to improve the speed here? Can this be run even more in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Because `analyticsService.getData(lesson.id)` is slow, most likely.

The assignment `val a = analyticsService.getData(lesson.id)` returns *immediately*, because (and I'm taking a small leap here) `analyticsService.getData(lesson.id)` is a `Future`. That means that when you reach the first `println`, the execution inside `analyticsService.getData(lesson.id)` *has not* completed, but has been dispatched within a `Future`.

The `println` statement inside `yield` does not execute until much later because it happens only after `Future.traverse` completes, which happens after all of its child futures complete.

Comment: quibble: when you write "only after Future.traverse completes ", I think you mean "only after the Future returned by Future.traverse completes". `Future.traverse` itself returns immediately.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet with a correct method of measuring how long the body takes as well as putting an example of why the code isn't running in parallel (replacing the Future method with `Future { Thread.sleep }`. The core issue is that the Future.traverse is too slow for me currently and I'm hoping to find ways of speeding it up.

Comment: @irregular Okay, then what `ExecutionContext` are you using? It looks like you're working with a fixed thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that `analyticsService.getData(lesson.id)` does operation that block for long periods of time inside a `Future`. `Thread.sleep` is one example.

You can surround that code in `blocking { ... }` (imported as `scala.concurrent.blocking`) to hint that to `ExecutionContext` so it could maybe allocate more threads.

Alternatively, you can use a different `ExecutionContext` for blocking I/O tasks, e.g. with unbounded thread pool:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import java.util.concurrent.{SynchronousQueue, ThreadPoolExecutor, TimeUnit}


implicit val ec: ExecutionContext =
  ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(new ThreadPoolExecutor(
    0, Int.MaxValue,
    60, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
    new SynchronousQueue[Runnable](false)))

/* your code here */
```

(this is blatantly stolen from [Scheduler.io factory method from Monix](https://github.com/monix/monix/blob/cb6f32d748bf764e074a745213b2be9bd707a1aa/monix-execution/jvm/src/main/scala/monix/execution/schedulers/SchedulerCompanionImpl.scala#L259))

Finally, in real life scenarios you might be able to significantly speed up everything if you can make `analyticsService.getData(lesson.id)` accept multiple IDs.